# Dump all databases to file

Tags: mysql, dump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Out of resources for mysqldump](https://serverfault.com/questions/104618/out-of-resources-for-mysqldump)

I'm trying to export all databases from my wamp installation (so I can do a reinstall), but I get this error when trying to generate a dump file:

> C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\bin>mysqldump -u root --all-databases >
>   dbs.sql mysqldump: Got error: 23: Out of resources when opening file
>   '.\site\posts_rg_lea d_detail.MYD' (Errcode: 24) when using LOCK
>   TABLES

the export stops after ~70 MB...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error 24 is : "Too many open files"

try this (add **--single-transation**):

`mysqldump -u root --all-databases --single-transaction > dbs.sql`

Comment: tx that works :D